# .net core PGP Encryption Decryption

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption, pgp

Running into error on the `void Encryption()`.

```
public void Encryption()
{
    #region PGP Encryption 

    PgpEncryptionKeys encryptionKeys = new PgpEncryptionKeys(@"C:\Keys\PGPPublicKey.asc", @"C:\Keys\PGPPrivateKey.asc", "password");
    PgpEncrypt encrypter = new PgpEncrypt(encryptionKeys);
    using (Stream outputStream = File.Create("C:\\Keys\\EncryptData.txt"))
    {
        encrypter.EncryptAndSign(outputStream, new FileInfo(@"D:\Keys\PlainText.txt"));
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Encryption Done !");

    #endregion
}
```

I used https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Pretty-Good-Privacy-using-4f473c67
as a reference.

I am confused about the parameters in the `PgpEncryptionKeys`.

Does anyone have a working example or help? This is my first time encrypting so I am little lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using by this way:

I think can help you!

**Helper:**

```
public static void EncryptPgpFile(string inputFile, string outputFile, string publicKeyFile, bool armor, bool withIntegrityCheck)
{
    using (Stream publicKeyStream = File.OpenRead(publicKeyFile))
    {
        PgpPublicKey pubKey = ReadPublicKey(publicKeyStream);

        using (MemoryStream outputBytes = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PgpCompressedDataGenerator dataCompressor = new PgpCompressedDataGenerator(CompressionAlgorithmTag.Zip);
            PgpUtilities.WriteFileToLiteralData(dataCompressor.Open(outputBytes), PgpLiteralData.Binary, new FileInfo(inputFile));

            dataCompressor.Close();
            PgpEncryptedDataGenerator dataGenerator = new PgpEncryptedDataGenerator(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag.Cast5, withIntegrityCheck, new SecureRandom());

            dataGenerator.AddMethod(pubKey);
            byte[] dataBytes = outputBytes.ToArray();

            using (Stream outputStream = File.Create(outputFile))
            {
                if (armor)
                {
                    using (ArmoredOutputStream armoredStream = new ArmoredOutputStream(outputStream))                   
                    using (Stream outputStream = dataGenerator.Open(armoredStream, dataBytes.Length))
                        outputStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
                }
                else
                {
                    using (Stream outputStream = dataGenerator.Open(armoredStream, dataBytes.Length))
                        outputStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private static PgpPublicKey ReadPublicKey(Stream inputStream)
{
    inputStream = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(inputStream);
    PgpPublicKeyRingBundle pgpPub = new PgpPublicKeyRingBundle(inputStream);

    foreach (PgpPublicKeyRing keyRing in pgpPub.GetKeyRings())
    {
        foreach (PgpPublicKey key in keyRing.GetPublicKeys())
        {
            if (key.IsEncryptionKey)
                return key;
        }
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("Can't find encryption key in key ring.");
}
```

**Usage:**

```
EncryptPgpFile(inputFile, outputFile, publicKeyPath, true, true);
```

Comment: I added PgpCore (1.3.1) to my project.

Where does PgpUtilities.WriteFileToLiteralData come from? It does not resolve for me with the above code.

Also, I changed the else dataGenerator.Open to use outputStream from the File.Create.

And... I renamed if and else stream to outStream since it clashed with the outer scope outputStream.. or was that intended?