# How to decrypt a Pgp-encrypted file using dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core, bouncycastle, openpgp

I have found an BouncyCastle OpenPgp package for encrypting/decrypting Pgp piles using dotnet Core. The repo is [here](https://github.com/chrishaly/bc-csharp), but there is no documentation. Does anyone know how to decrypt a file encrypted using Pgp?

Comment: Sorry! I cannot answer you! I posted an answer but it was gawked at. Take solace in knowing that the answer is out there!

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52224818/net-core-pgp-encryption-decryption