# C# - pgp_sym_decrypt?

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database where I use the `pgp_sym_encrypt()` function to crypt data

```sql
INSERT INTO public.product(name, brand, size, price)
    VALUES (pgp_sym_encrypt('product1', 'AES_KEY'), 'brand 1', 1, 1);
```

And it works with `pgp_sym_decrypt()`

```sql
SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt(name::bytea, 'AES_KEY') FROM public.product;
```

Is there some equivalent code in c# to decrypt the data which are crypted with the `pgp_sym_encrypt()` function ?

I tried this kind of code but I always get the crypted data

```cs
using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
{
    aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("AES_KEY");
    aes.IV = new byte[16];
    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

    var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    {
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream)memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader((Stream)cryptoStream))
            {
             return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't using `AES` despite the `'AES_KEY'` you put in the code, you are using PGP/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.net core PGP Encryption Decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52224818/net-core-pgp-encryption-decryption)

Comment: @Charlieface you mean PGP on the PostgreSQL side  ? Even if i use `pgp_sym_encrypt('product1', 'AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODw==','cipher-algo=aes128')` ?

Comment: You didn't say that. But it would still be a PGP message, which means you need to decrypt it using PGP functions. Why don't you just decrypt it in Postgres?

Comment: So it will be always a PGP message ? IT explains a lot !